# Filtering XML file, with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I want to load XML file and then remove all `<Charge>` where `<DispositionDate>` is bigger/older then 7 years. Date format is YYYY-MM-DD.

XML example:

```
<BackgroundReports userId="" password="" account="" >
    <BackgroundReportPackage>
        <Screenings>
            <Screening type="criminal" qualifier="">
                <CriminalReport>
                    <CriminalCase>
                        <AgencyReference type="Docket">
                            <IdValue>CR-0870120-09</IdValue>
                        </AgencyReference>
                        <Charge>
                            <ChargeId>
                                <IdValue>1</IdValue>
                            </ChargeId>
                            <ChargeOrComplaint>DUI: HIGHEST RTE OF ALC (BAC .16+) 1ST OFF</ChargeOrComplaint>
                            <ChargeTypeClassification>unknown</ChargeTypeClassification>
                            <DispositionDate>2009-04-07</DispositionDate>
                        </Charge>
                        <Charge>
                            <ChargeId>
                                <IdValue>2</IdValue>
                            </ChargeId>
                            <ChargeOrComplaint>CARELESS DRIVING</ChargeOrComplaint>
                            <ChargeTypeClassification>unknown</ChargeTypeClassification>
                            <DispositionDate>2010-08-02</DispositionDate>
                        </Charge>
                        <Charge>
                            <ChargeId>
                                <IdValue>3</IdValue>
                            </ChargeId>
                            <ChargeOrComplaint>STATUTE: 475 PC</ChargeOrComplaint>
                            <ChargeTypeClassification>misdemeanor</ChargeTypeClassification>
                            <OffenseDate>1988-11-05</OffenseDate>
                            <Disposition>CONVICTED</Disposition>
                            <DispositionDate>1988-11-09</DispositionDate>
                            <DispositionDate>1988-11-05</DispositionDate>
                            <DispositionDate>1988-11-09</DispositionDate>
                        </Charge>
                    </CriminalCase>
                </CriminalReport>
            </Screening>
        </Screenings>
    </BackgroundReportPackage>
</BackgroundReports>
```

I know how to open and close/save file using PHP, I don't know how to delete the part i don't want... If anyone would help me with that I would be extremly thankfull!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use [SimpleXML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), [DOM](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or [XSL](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) for it.

#### Example XML ([shortened for brevity (from Revision 1 of your question)](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5d70b643-ca53-49bd-9caa-32c37bd4a9ef/view-source)):

```
$xml = <<< XML
<CriminalCase>
    <Charge>
        <DispositionDate>1995-12-21</DispositionDate>
    </Charge>
    <Charge>
        <DispositionDate>2010-12-21</DispositionDate>
    </Charge>
</CriminalCase>
XML;
```

---

#### With SimpleXml

```
$sevenYearsAgo = new DateTime('-7 years');
$CriminalCase  = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);
for ($i = 0; $i < $CriminalCase->Charge->count(); $i++) {
    $dispositionDate = new DateTime($CriminalCase->Charge->DispositionDate);
    if ($dispositionDate < $sevenYearsAgo) {
        unset($CriminalCase->Charge[$i]);
    }
}
echo $CriminalCase->asXml();
```

---

#### With DOM

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$oldCases = $xpath->query(
    sprintf(
        '//Charge[substring-before(DispositionDate, "-") < %d]',
        date('Y', strtotime('-7 years'))
    )
);
foreach ($oldCases as $oldCase) {
    $oldCase->parentNode->removeChild($oldCase);
}
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

---

#### With XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
                extension-element-prefixes="date">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <CriminalCase>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </CriminalCase>      
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Charge">
    <xsl:if test="date:year(DispositionDate) &gt; date:year() - 7">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and then use this PHP Code to transform it

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
$doc->loadXml($xsl);
$xsl->importStyleSheet($doc);
$doc->loadXml($xml);
echo $xsl->transformToXML($doc);
```

Comment: awesome, i will try DOM first .P

Comment: Could you please check the NEW xml i've pasted, that's for example actual XML I'm using, I couldn't get it work so far, after 12 hours of trying. I've tried SimpleXML and DOM :S Could you repost your examples according to my XML sample? THANKS!!!

Comment: @Pro unless I dont understand the question, the DOM solution works for me with that XML: http://codepad.viper-7.com/y38Bw2. The SimpleXML solution would need tweaking because of the different XML though but it's trivial to do, so I wont update it.

Comment: I got it working using DOM, I was completely blunt and forgot to close php file with `?>`, not sure why there was no error shown for that.

Comment: My real and final questions is => How can I write that I remove WHOLE `<CriminalCase>`-es when there is only one `<Charge>` and that one `<Charge>` is older then 7 years, but if there is two charges and only one is older then 7 years, only the `<Charge>` should get removed and not whole `<CriminalCase>`. This is bit tricky I guess.

Comment: @ProDraz yeah, its a bit tricky if you want to do it in one go. The easiest way would be to first use the code above and then do a second iteration removing all `//CriminalCase[not(Charge)]`

Comment: No need, to do it in one go :P Mind posting sample. Also can I donate you for a BEER or something?

Comment: @ProDraz its the same code as in the DOM example above. All you have to change is the XPath. Removing nodes is always the same with DOM. And yes, I will happily have a beer with you should we ever meet at a conference or someplace else.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips on how to get started:

1. You need to parse the XML to something a little easier to work with. PHP has a library called [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).
2. Loop through the data and remove the objects which are older than 7 years. To compare dates you have to first convert the dates you got from the XML to something PHP can process as a date. Take a look at [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) which gives you the timestamp (seconds since 1970, actually 1901 for version > 5.1.0) or [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) which supports dates before 1970.
3. To check if the fetched date is older than 7 years ago, you need to (one way) subtract the timestamp with the current timestamp, and see if that value is greater than 7 years in seconds. Or if you use DateTime, you can take a look at [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php). Remove the objects that you iterate over that are older than 7 years ([unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)).
4. To save as XML again, take a look at [SimpleXMLElement::asXML](http://no.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't want to convert XML, I just want to edit it. I'm transforming XML later on, with XSLT ... Altough I think only way will be to parse it with SimpleXML :S

Comment: Well, you kind of need to convert it to XML to save it to file.