# Filter xml data by date using php

Tags: php, xml, date, xml-parsing

I want to filter my xml data by date using php

```
<xml>
<customer>
  <cid>1</cid>
  <amount_paid>1000</amount_paid>
  <date>2012-01-10</date>
</customer>
<customer>
  <cid>2</cid>
  <amount_paid>3000</amount_paid>
  <date>2012-01-10</date>
</customer>
<customer>
  <cid>3</cid>
  <amount_paid>1000</amount_paid>
  <date>2012-01-05</date>
</customer>
<customer>
  <cid>6</cid>
  <amount_paid>7000</amount_paid>
  <date>2012-01-21</date>
</customer>
</xml>
```

How can filter my xml by date?
For example. I want get customers where date = "2012-01-10"

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering XML file, with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810645/filtering-xml-file-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/s1YcOf)

```
<?php
    $string = '<xml>
<customer>
  <cid>1</cid>
  <amount_paid>1000</amount_paid>
  <date>2012-01-10</date>
</customer>
<customer>
  <cid>2</cid>
  <amount_paid>3000</amount_paid>
  <date>2012-01-10</date>
</customer>
<customer>
  <cid>3</cid>
  <amount_paid>1000</amount_paid>
  <date>2012-01-05</date>
</customer>
<customer>
  <cid>6</cid>
  <amount_paid>7000</amount_paid>
  <date>2012-01-21</date>
</customer>
</xml>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

foreach ($xml->customer AS $customer)
{
    if ($customer->date == '2012-01-10')
    {
        echo $customer->cid . "<br>\n";
        echo $customer->amount_paid . "<br>\n";
    }
}
```