# PHP - Get specific fields from xml file

Tags: php, xml, xpath

with the following partial code I get XML data via an API

```
$xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

$xmlObj->registerXPathNamespace( 'N', 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim');

$sfield = $xmlObj->xpath( '//N:datafield[@tag="550"]/N:subfield[@code="a"]' );
```

It works. But now I want to filter the data I receive

1. I just want to get the data with code="a" from tag="550" where the value for code="i" is "Funktion"
2. I just want to get the data with code="a" from tag="550" where the value for code="i" is not "Funktion".

How can i do that with xpath?

Example XML with "Funktion"

```
<datafield tag="550" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
<subfield code="a">Text</subfield>
<subfield code="4">funk</subfield>
<subfield code="4">http://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/gnd#functionOrRole</subfield>
<subfield code="w">r</subfield>
<subfield code="i">Funktion</subfield>
</datafield>
```

Example XML without "Funktion"

```
<datafield tag="550" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
<subfield code="0">(DE-101)041251733</subfield>
<subfield code="0">(DE-588)4125173-8</subfield>
<subfield code="0">http://d-nb.info/gnd/4125173-8</subfield>
<subfield code="a">Grafiker</subfield>
<subfield code="4">beru</subfield>
<subfield code="4">http://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/gnd#professionOrOccupation</subfield>
<subfield code="w">r</subfield>
<subfield code="i">Beruf</subfield>
</datafield>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810645/filtering-xml-file-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest and combine conditions. So step by step:

- Fetch any `datafield` element
  `//N:datafield`
- ...with an attribute `tag` that is `550`
  `//N:datafield[@tag="550"]`
- ...and with an child element `subfield`
  `//N:datafield[@tag="550" and N:subfield]`
- ...that has an attribute `code` with the value `i`
  `//N:datafield[@tag="550" and N:subfield[@code="i"]]`
- ...the text contents of that `subfield` should be `Funktion`
  `//N:datafield[@tag="550" and N:subfield[@code="i"] = "Funktion"]`
- ...and get the `subfield` child of the `datafield`
  `//N:datafield[@tag="550" and N:subfield[@code="i"] = "Funktion"]/N:datafield`
- ...that has an attribute `code` with the value `a`
  `//N:datafield[@tag="550" and N:subfield[@code="i"] = "Funktion"]/N:datafield[@code="a"]`

For the second expression you can just use `not()` on that particular expression.

- ...the text contents of that `subfield` should be `Funktion`
  `//N:datafield[@tag="550" and not(N:subfield[@code="i"] = "Funktion")]`

Whitespace in Xpath expressions are mostly ignored (not before a leading `/`). So you can wrap and indent you expression to make them more readable.

Put together:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<foo xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
  <datafield tag="550">
    <subfield code="a">Text</subfield>
    <subfield code="i">Funktion</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="550">
    <subfield code="a">Grafiker</subfield>
    <subfield code="i">Beruf</subfield>
  </datafield>
</foo>
XML;

$element = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$element->registerXPathNamespace( 'N', 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim');

$expression = '//N:datafield[
  @tag="550" and N:subfield[@code="i"] = "Funktion"
]/N:subfield[@code="a"]';

foreach ($element->xpath($expression) as $field) {
    var_dump((string)$field);
}

echo str_repeat('-', 25), "\n";

$expression = '//N:datafield[
  @tag="550" and not(N:subfield[@code="i"] = "Funktion")
]/N:subfield[@code="a"]';

foreach ($element->xpath($expression) as $field) {
    var_dump((string)$field);
}
```

Output:

```
string(4) "Text" 
------------------------- 
string(8) "Grafiker"
```

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. Works perfectly.  The other answers are also good. Many thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath query

```
$sfield = $xmlObj->xpath('//N:datafield[@tag="550"][subfield[@code="a"]][subfield[@code="i"][text()="Funktion"]]');
```

Note that `[text()="Funktion"]` filter element has text `Funktion`

Comment: Not exactly. It checks that here is a child text node with the content `Funktion`. In most cases that does not matter. Only if the actual text content is in several nodes (If you have mixed nodes and inline formatting like in (x)html). `[. = "Funktion"]` compares the whole text content of a node.